# Moving Data from one column to another similar column in another table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a webbased systen using a Mysql db.

I realised that I had initially set up the columns within the tables incorrectly and

I now need to move the data from one table column (receiptno) in table (clients) into a similar table column(receiptno) in table (revenue).

I am still quite inexperienced with Mysql and therefore I dont know the the mysql syntax to accomplish this.

Can I get some help on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you simply wanted to insert the data into new records within the `revenue` table:

```
INSERT INTO revenue (receiptno) SELECT receiptno FROM clients;
```

However, if you want to update existing records in the `revenue` table with the associated data from the `clients` table, you would have to join the tables and perform an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE revenue JOIN clients ON **join_condition_here**
SET    revenue.receiptno = clients.receiptno;
```

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 5):

Same smell, different odor to eggyal's answer, this works in Oracle and Postgress so your mileage may vary.

```
UPDATE revenue t1 SET receiptno = (
  SELECT receiptno FROM clients t2 WHERE t2.client_id = t1.revenue_id
);
```

You will have to adjust the where clause to suit your needs ...

Comment: In Oracle, receiptno will update to null if not matched. Seem like this is not the exactly accurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO newtable (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT filed1, field2, field3
FROM oldtable
```